# WordPress shows registration link for non logged users

Tags: php, login, user-registration, cms

I have a WordPress site and I want to add a registration link for visitors.

So, I added a menu item called 'REGISTER' with the following link:

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?action=register
```

The problem is that this link opens the registration form for both users and visitors and I want to show it only to visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the problem with Nav Menu Roles plugin

I added the registration link to the menu and with the plugin and i set it to only logged out users

This way it won't show to logged users

Answer (score 2):

Add your registration or log in link inside of the `is_user_logged_in()` function. So If the current user not logged on your site then this function will show the login page for them and that user If not registered he/she must have to register in order to log in to your site.

Code example:

```
<?php
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
  <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>">Log in / Register</a>
}
```

Comment: i know but i want to add this code in the whole wordpress not just a specific page

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wp_nav_menu_items` filter to conditionally add a menu item. Add this code to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_custom_menu_item( $items, $args ) {
    if( !is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary-menu' ) {
        $items .= '<li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpse_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
```